# How to parallel two voltage signals

Tags: voltage, signal, parallel

To parallel two buffered signals voltage I mean to get (scan) the voltage which has the higher absolute value if they are in the same polarity, and get the summation of two vantage value if they are in opposite polarity. For example

```
 Vs1           Vs2             Expect output
 3.5v          1.3v              3.5v
-4.1v         -5.2v             -5.2v
 1.7v         -0.6v              1.1v
-2.5v          3.9v              1.4v
```

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Your question is short of detail and constraints. (1) What output do you want? 1 mA or 10 A? (2) What is the power supply for your circuit? (3) It might also help if you explain the background to this question: is it homework or a real world problem? (4) What have you done to solve it so far? (5) What components are you allowed use. Put all the information in the question and not sprinkled through the comments.

Comment: Huh? What? Closing.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest (for some folk) will be to use a small MCU with a couple of ADC inputs and a DAC output then you can use the power of the MCU to do what you want by comparing digital representations of the signal levels.

But this method (and a straight analogue-ish) method raises questions such as: -

- How accurate do you want the output level to be?
- How accurate do you want the input signal testing mechanism to be?
- What speed or frequency might the inputs be changing at?

If you were to use an analogue method I would make three circuits that: -

- Produced the positive maximum (using op-amp precision rectifers) output
- Produced the negative maximum (using op-amp precision rectifers) output
- Produced the sum and then precision rectified the output to get only a positive result

I would then make three circuits that tested each scenario (using comparators) and, with additional steering logic, I would enable analogue switches to select one of the three outputs I wanted to be my final output.